# How to design tables to allow users to create their web page, with preview, save and publish features?

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I am building a site, and among other things, I need to allow a user to create their custom landing page.

Each user will upload their own header image, create a custom title, description, and other content.

Currently, I have a table that holds all the page elements.
But I want to enable users to have a draft version of the page while a published version might already exist.
And while they are editing their page, I want to allow the users to preview their work (for example, clicking a "preview" button while editing).

What is the best way to achieve the above in terms of database tables?

For example, the main table containing the elements of the saved finalized and published page is something like the following:

**user_page** table

```
user_id: Integer -  foreign key to the user table
header_image: Varchar - contains the name of the image, save on S3
title: Varchar - the title of the page
description: Text - some page content
```

At the moment, I think that to have a preview mode, which is a non-published page, I could have another table, identical to the `user_page` table called for example `preview_user_page`.

So while the users are editing their page, I save all in `preview_user_page`. And when they click the preview button, I show the page with the content stored in the `preview_user_page`.

When the users are ready and press the publish button, I copy their content into the `user_page` table, providing the data for the posted finalized page.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Just to be clear, are you developing a CMS?

Comment: No, it is not a CMS. It's just a site that allows users to have their own semi-customized single page that they can share. It has nothing to do with LinkedIn but imaging the LinkedIn users' own profile page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need for extra tables. Just add a column that designates, if a row stores a draft or a published version. The details, like constraints or column data type(s) depend on the details you envision there -- Can there be multiple drafts, possibly named or designated by a timestamp or version number? Should an unpublished page be degraded to a draft or be delete all together? ...

For the simple case that there can maximally be one draft and of course only maximally one published page, that could be something along the lines of (assuming that the users table is called `"user"` and has an `integer` column `id` as its (single column) primary key):

```
CREATE TYPE user_page_status
            AS ENUM('draft',
                    'published');

CREATE TABLE user_page
             (user_id integer,
              header_image text,
              title text,
              description text,
              status user_page_status,
              PRIMARY KEY (user_id,
                           status),
              FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
                          REFERENCES "user"
                                     (id));
```

(The implicit unique constraint the primary key introduces ensures that there cannot be more than one page of a status for a user. The implicit not null constraints make sure a page belongs to a user and has a status.)

In this example you can use the `state` column to decide whether to get a draft -- `WHERE status = 'draft' AND ...` -- or a published page -- `WHERE status = 'published' AND ...`.

And why do you think you need to persist data of a preview in the database (again)? If you want to show the preview of an existing draft or a published page, that data already is in the database. Get it and parse it. If you want to show a preview of a not yet saved draft, WYSIWYG-style, you already have the data in your application's memory, just parse that. There's no need to first write it to the database just to retrieve it again immediately afterwards and then promptly delete it in the database.

Comment: If I don't duplicate the content into another table, while users are editing their page the content will reflect in the live published page.

Comment: @andrea: I don't understand. In your question you wrote that you want to give the users the possibility to save drafts, now you write you want to let them only directly change the single live page? Then neither more tables nor more rows are needed. Update the existing row in the existing table.

Comment: I don't think I wrote two different things. Let me try again.

I cannot store the data into the application memory, which I assume you might mean the session of the currently logged-in user, because if they log out they lose all their work.

Imaging there is already a published page that the user has created previously.
Now a month later they want to make changes to that page. While they make the changes they want to preview their work without affecting their currently published page.

Comment: @andrea: (1) There is a current page that is displayed when the user's profile is asked for or whatever the trigger is to show it, and that is created with the values currently stored in the database, right? (2) If a user wants to edit the page, the application loads the values from the database and provides the user with some means, say a form, to edit the values, right? (3) They can then save their changes which will cause the values to be stored in the database again, right? So between (2) and (3) the values are in the application's memory.

Comment: OK, I see now the part that is unclear. 
(2) Is something that the users can start on a computer at their job location during their lunch break. 
The lunch break ends but they haven't finished updating the page. So they don't want to hit publish. They want to save their work and continue the editing in the evening when they go back home and pick up from where they left off on their home computer.

Comment: @andrea: Well, then they can save the current values as a draft and the values are stored in the table with a marker, that this is only a draft, as I outlined in the answer. If they wish to continue their work, the application loads the values from the draft stored in the database. ...

Comment: @andrea: ... The "the application has the values in memory" part of my answer is *solely* meant for the previews of unsaved (neither as published nor as draft) pages, i.e. the current values a user has in the form, if edited by them or not. You don't need to write these current values, which aren't supposed to be published or saved as a draft (yet) to the database to then just receive them again to render the preview.

Comment: I understand your application's memory part now. When not required I would not save anything into the database if I can just pick the value from the memory.

But there are use cases, as described in my previous comments when I need to store update values in some kind of draft form that does not affect the currently live published page.

I like your idea of not duplicating data, but I don't understand how can I not duplicate the data.

Comment: Maybe you could update your answer with an example table so that I can understand how I can both retrieve draft data between sessions and not affect the current live page.

Comment: @andrea: Have a look at the edit.

Comment: @andrea In case it still isn't clear, when a *draft* is saved, of course you'll need to save a *copy* of the data but you won't need to save it to a copy of **the table**. That is, you can use a single table to store both the live version and draft versions of the webpage, and distinguish between the two with a single additional column `IsDraft` or `user_page_status` (as sticky bit mentioned) etc.

Comment: @j-d Thank you, yes, I understand that a copy of the data is necessary but not a duplicate table. My question was just about where to save this duplicate data. I gave my thoughts and asked if there was a better way. I am grateful to @sticky-bit; the example he added to his answer showed me the better way.